# Compiling Torch on Ubuntu 17.04: No Support for GCC version >5 and Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

Tags: compiling, gcc, 17.04, cuda

During my installation of torch on Ubuntu 17.04, I ran into a few problems.

The first report after trying to compile torch was something similar to 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622454/cuda-incompatible-with-my-gcc-version

giving me something like

```
error -- unsupported GNU version! gcc >5 are not supported!
```

After I fixed this I got another error similar to here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11912878/gcc-error-gcc-error-trying-to-exec-cc1-execvp-no-such-file-or-directory

```
Gcc error: gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

Want to also add here that this is in conjunction with my cuda setup.

Comment: Please include the actual steps you performed.

Comment: you're too fast for my typing! 2 minutes ahead of me, but answer is now posted.

Comment: Additionally, I have had to upgrade my Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10 via sudo do-release-upgrade as 17.04 is reached end of life as of January 13, 2018

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the first error by installing gcc-5:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5
```

next, it said it couldnt find cc1, so i did

```
which cc1
```

which returned a blank. This was because I didn't install g++-5

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
```

we next want to make this our default gcc, so

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 1
```

and finally

```
./install.sh
```

in the torch directory works. This is similar to the approach here:
https://gist.github.com/beci/2a2091f282042ed20cda

torch getting started that started it all: http://torch.ch/docs/getting-started.html

hope  this helps someone

Comment: `which cc1` still returns blank. But this works!

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same error messag:

> gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory

I googled and arrived here. So for the sake of helping people with my same problem... My error was in a different context: trying to compile a go program importing the go-sqlite3 driver...

in my case (ubuntu 16.10 yakkety yak) `sudo find /usr/ -name cc1` showed me that cc1 was installed, even several versions:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/cc1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/cc1
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/cc1
```

I did run `which gcc` and could see that gcc was pointing to my nvidia cuda driver bin directory, which was including gcc...

In my case this was some residual stuff I didn't uninstall properly, so I had to manually remove that directory from my `$PATH` in my `.bashrc`. The I closed my terminal (I've could have run `source ~/.bashrc`), verified with `which gcc` that it was pointing to the proper one (`/usr/bin/gcc`) tried to recompile my go program and it worked without any errors this time.

I know this may not be the perfect answer, but it may point a perso having the same error message to investigate further this kind of stuff.

Of course check which version of gcc you are using, and install the "companion" g++ you need. In my case it was: `g++-4.9` (already installed).